# Use an expression as `lhs` in a mapping

Tags: key-bindings

I know that if I do:

```
:inoremap <expr> . InsertDot()
```

the result of `InsertDot()` will be inserted as `{rhs}` of the mapping.

I need to do the same but with the `{lhs}`, in order to be able to define some dynamic mappings that will take as key sequence what is defined in a var.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `execute` command. If your lhs is in the variable `l:lhs` you can do:

```
execute "inoremap <expr> " . l:lhs . " InsertDot()"
```

`execute` will expand the content of the variable and then execute the string obtained by the concatenation of the quoted string and the value of the variable.

See [`:h :execute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:execute) for more details.